# Как найти картинки, используемые в приложении

Tags: resources, grab

Нужно достать несколько картинок из Microsoft SQLServer Management Studio. Если конкретнее, то иконки графа для отображения плана запроса

Что уже пытался сделать:

- В папке "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" выбрал через поиск все библиотеки dll и распаковал их пр  помощи 7-zip. После чего в папке, куда они распаковались, делал поиск *.ico *.bmp, нашел много картинок, но не нашел тех, которые искал.
- Открывал Management Studio через Dependency Walker, чтобы найти все исользуемые библиотеки, но он отобразил только user32, kernel и тд.
- Открывал исполняемый файл через Resource Hacker, но он показал только те картинки, которые зашиты в exe файле, и не показал связанных.

Comment: ResHacker на DLL натравливайте, они тоже могут содержать ресурсы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, прочитайте вопрос еще раз. После "Что уже пытался сделать:"

Comment: Прочитал, про reshacker на чем-то кроме одного единственного файла ничего не сказано.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тогда прочитайте первый пункт.

Comment: Еще раз: reshacker и 7z - разные вещи.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вы правы, 7-zip помимо всего прочего умеет не только извлекать ресурсы, но еще и распаковывать архивы

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я бы с радостью поэкспериментировал с этим, но там пара сотен dll.

Comment: Тогда IDA и отладчик - ваши верные друзья.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос с доставанием картинок из любого приложения так и не решен, но, если кому интересно, нашел нужные мне картинки с описанием здесь

[Graphical Execution Plan Icons (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175913.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)